# Saving username and password using UISwitch in Swift

Tags: swift, passwords, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

Ive searched a lot of threads and this is my last resort because Ive seen this question asked different ways but not exactly for swift and for Username and password saving. I want my UISwitch when turned on to save my username and password info. I've been trying all day to get this UISwitch to save my username and password using NSUserDefaults. Please help me I'm at my whits end with trying it, I've searched almost every forum to find the answer but not many people show you exactly how to implement it. Below is my code. I know its bleak, as I am a beginner, but I have my "Login Button" saving my username and password, but i don't know how to get it to only save that information when I click the UISwitch and how to save it in the "view did load method".  thanks for the help in advance!! I don't know what code to include into my UISwitch Method.
Here is the first part of my login button and then my view did load method. I don't have any code for the UISwitchMethod

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

//Save username and password info if Save UISwitch is selected

  switchState.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchState")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("keepUsername")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("keepPassword")

}

@IBAction func LoginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

var username = self.usernameTextField.text
var password = self.passwordTextField.text
var user = PFUser.currentUser()


NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(username, forKey: "keepUsername")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(password, forKey: "keepPassword")

if count(username) < 4 || count(password) < 5 {

  var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Sorry!", message: "Username Must be greater than 4 characters and the password greater that 5 characters", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")

  alert.show()    
}else { 
  self.actInd.startAnimating()
  PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: password, block: { (user, NSError) -> Void in

    self.actInd.stopAnimating()

    if ((user) != nil) {

      println("Success \(user) logged in")

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toHomeFromLogin", sender: self)

    }else {
       var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "error", message: "Please Sign up :)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
      alert.show()
    }


 @IBAction func switchStateChanged(sender: UISwitch) {


NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(switchState.on, forKey: "switchState")

  }
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more explicit in your question, I can see you are reading the values for keepUsername and keepPassoword as boolean, NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("keepUsername") and you are not even trying to save it in any variable or constant, so I am to confuse about what you are trying to archive to be able to help you

Comment: Hey IcaroNz,  sorry about the vagueness of the question, but when I input a username and password into my app and press the Login button, I'm saving the username and password as objects, and I'm trying to have them appear in the app only if  the "save user info" UISwitch is turned on. Im struggling on knowing what code to include in the UISwitch method and how to properly implement it with the NSUserdefault statements. Im certain my code is wrong, but Im struggling on finding resources to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the moment look like you have an IBAction inside another IBAction as I can't see the end of LoginButton (what should be lowercase). Past a better version of the code and I help you to get it working.

Comment: Sorry i did poorly input the code, hope this gives you a clearer picture. I read that i need that info in the view did load method so that the app will know to display the username and password if it has been saved.

Comment: I did a review on windows so I can't guarantee I didn't miss something or misspell something, but I think that should give you the answers you need.

Comment: thanks man thats awesome!  thanks for taking the time to help out! really appreciate it!! haver a great day bud!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will add some notes and edits I would do and I hope it can help you:

```
   var switchState = Bool()
   var userName = String()
   var password = String()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//Load all values

    switchState = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchState")
    userName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("keepUsername")
    password = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("keepPassword")
    //Display values somewhere
}

@IBAction func LoginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var enteredUser = self.usernameTextField.text
    var enteredPassword = self.passwordTextField.text
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(enteredUser, forKey: "keepUsername")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(enteredPassword, forKey: "keepPassword")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    if count(username) < 4 || count(password) < 5 {
        var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Sorry!", message: "Username Must be greater than 4 characters and the password greater that 5 characters", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")   
        alert.show()    
    }else { 
       self.actInd.startAnimating()
       PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: password, block: { (user, NSError) -> Void in 
       self.actInd.stopAnimating(   
        if ((user) != nil) {
             println("Success \(user) logged in")
             self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toHomeFromLogin", sender: self)
         }else {
             var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "error", message: "Please Sign up :)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
         alert.show()
    }
 @IBAction func switchStateChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
    //var readValueFromSwitch = something bolean
    //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(readValueFromSwitch, forKey: "switchState")
    //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I send you the hole page so you can get and idea and also there is a way you can send alert messages for the Register page, look the //store data

import UIKit

class RegisterPageViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var repeatPasswordTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text;

    // Check for empty fields
    if (userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty)
    {

        // Display alert message

        displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required");

        return;

    }
    // Check if passwords match
    if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword)
    {
      //Display an alert message
        displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match");

        return;
    }

    // Store data
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userEmail, forKey: "userEmail");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userPassword, forKey: "userPassword");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();


    // Display alert message with confirmation.
    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration successful, Thank you!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){action in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
    }

    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);

}

func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{

    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil);

    myAlert.addAction(okAction);

    self.presentViewController(myAlert , animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}